# adding a reverb effect to my audio file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a javascript code that causes a reverb to an audio file.the audio file is a recorded audio file using html5.I want to be able to add the reverb effect to that file.I tried searching Google for anycode. but could not find or sometimes find something hard to follow if someone can please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several libraries on github enabling this:

https://github.com/web-audio-components/simple-reverb

https://github.com/Dinahmoe/tuna

What they eventually do, is using the AudioContext api to create a convolver(which is also an option if you dont want to use the libraries).

The principle is:

1.)Load the file via Ajax, get the response, and use AudioContext.decodeAudioData saved to a variable.

2.)Create an audio context, and instead connecting it straight to .destination, add a a convolver using the .createConvolver()

The audioContext api documentation would help you a lot:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createConvolver

Comment: I'm new to javascript so bare with I'm using the demo http://www.danieldemmel.me/JSSoundRecorder/ found in github, in the edit page of that demo is the colection of filters so I want to add effects to those.can I apply what you offered me in that project also?will it be suitable?

Comment: The example you sent does not work in firefox nor in chrome. there is a function `startUserMedia(stream)` you need to create the convolution object inside after you fix the code compatability issues(seems like dated code in the audio api) i suggest you try to create yourself a stream from microphone to output using an example from the documentation, later on chaining the built in effects - or effects from a library.

Answer (score 3):

**Update December 2015**: The <audio> tag in HTML5 does not give you any direct way to change the sound of the source audio file. Therefore, you need to go another level deeper and use the more advanced Web Audio API.

Since there is not just one way to do reverb (there are many room types, algorithms, etc.), the Web Audio API provides support for a convolution node, which is a generalization of reverb-, filter-, and delay- type effects. Convolution allows you to accurately reproduce nearly any space with an impulse response (generally, an audio recording of a percussive sound). Using the convolution node is a little bit tricky to get right, and it still doesn't solve the problem of selecting the specific room you are trying to reproduce.

To make this easier, I've written a reverb wrapper library around the Web Audio API's convolution node called **Reverb.js** (http://reverbjs.org). The project also hosts a growing number of Creative Commons-licensed impulse responses that you can freely use, or you can use your own. It can also load audio from a Base64 string, so you can entirely embed the impulse response and/or the sound in your HTML document. Finally, an integration example accompanies each impulse response, which makes selecting and using a particular reverb more convenient.